# Passing arguments to a running electron app

Tags: electron

I have found some search results about using `app.makeSingleInstance` and using CLI arguments, but it seems that the command has been removed.

Is there any other way to send a string to an already started electron app?

Comment: send a string from where? Is launching a child process that communicates to your electron app an option?

Comment: For example from a shell or another node app. What kind of child process could that be?

Comment: I was thinking about spawning a child process from your electron app (e.g. a Console app; .exe) that sits around while its running and periodically sends it messages. If that's a suitable solution, I can post an example. Is a C# executable fine?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be a suitable solution for my particular problem. Maybe i should give a bit more context. What i want to do is if a user selects text (for example in a browser or a program) and presses a shortcut, then i want to send this text to the electron app. I have a program that copies the marked text. Now i just need a way to transfer this text to the electron app from outside. Is there no way to set up a kind of systemwide event listener?

Comment: You can use [`globalShortcuts`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut) for the shortcut part of it. Does it make sense for your program to run when your electron app isn't running? Or should your electron app be starting the program

Comment: I read about globalShortcuts but since it doesn't accept arguments, I actually ignored it. My plan is to use only one shortcut, either via electron or another program, to pass the selected text to the electron app. I'll probably run the second program independently from the electron app. The idea with the second program is only an idea of a workaround, as electron can't "pull" selected text from within other apps on its own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190395/discussion-between-pushkin-and-niko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the most elegant solution to my particular problem was to add a http api endpoint for the Electron app using [koa](https://koajs.com).

```
const Koa = require("koa");
const koa = new Koa();

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  let startServer = function() {
    koa.use(async ctx => {
        mainWindow.show();
        console.log("text received", ctx.request.query.text);
        ctx.body = ctx.request.query.text;
    });

    koa.listen(3456);
  };
}
```

Now I can easily send texts to Electron from outside the app using the following url:

```
localhost:3456?text=myText
```

Answer (score 1):

One strategy is to have your external program write to a file that your electron app knows about. Then, your electron app can listen for changes to that file and can read it to get the string:

```
import fs

fs.watch("shared/path.txt", { persistent: false }, (eventType: string, fileName: string) => {
    if (eventType === "change") {
        const myString: string = fs.readFileSync(fileName, { encoding: "utf8" });
    }
});
```

I used the synchronous `readFileSync` for simplicity, but you might want to consider the async version.

Second, you'll need to consider the case where this external app is writing so quickly that maybe the `fs.watch` callback is triggered only once for two writes. Could you miss a change?

Otherwise, I don't believe there's an Electron-native way of getting this information from an external app. If you were able to start the external app from your Electron app, then you could just do `cp.spawn(...)` and use its `stdout` pipe to listen for messages.

If shared memory were a thing in Node, then you could use that, but unfortunately [it's not](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/560).